# How to cancel JavaScript sleep?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

This function is used to wait for millis number of second.

```
function delay(millis: number) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, millis);
    });
```

My goal is then to return the timeout out of this function?

```
const timeout = await delay(20000);
```

on click somewhere else, user bored of waiting

```
clearTimeout(timeout)
```

Comment: `timeout` won't be set until the promise is resolved, even if you did pass it to `resolve()`.. Also, that won't wait `millis` number of seconds; it will wait `millis` number of milliseconds.

Comment: return both the promise and timer id.

Comment: but still clearing `timeout` will not resolve the promise, and it will not proceed after await.

Comment: Nowadays it has a better way to _abort_ it. I won’t share it here though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply extend the Promise object you'll be sending:

```js
function delay( millis ) {
  let timeout_id;
  let rejector;
  const prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    rejector = reject;
    timeout_id = setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, millis);
  });
  prom.abort = () => {
    clearTimeout( timeout_id );
    rejector( 'aborted' );
  };
  return prom;
}

const will_abort = delay( 2000 );
const will_not_abort = delay( 2000 );

will_abort
  .then( () => console.log( 'will_abort ended' ) )
  .catch( console.error );

will_not_abort
  .then( () => console.log( 'will_not_abort ended' ) )
  .catch( console.error );

setTimeout( () => will_abort.abort(), 1000 );
```

Comment: Great solution, but remember to assign setTimeout to `timeout_id`.

`timeout_id = setTimeout(resolve, millis);`

Comment: @Henning yes thanks for the heads up. Note that it's actually not *necessary* to clear the timeout here since a Promise can only be resolved or rejected once, but still, it's probably better this way, at least because it's useless to keep that function to execute.

Answer (score 1):

You can return the resolve / reject along with the promise

```js
function delay(millis) {
    let reolver;
    return [new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolver = resolve
        x = setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, millis);
    }), resolver];
}  

const [sleep1, wake1] = delay(2000)
sleep1.then((x) => console.log(x || 'wakeup 1')) // Auto wake after 2 seconds

const [sleep2, wake2] = delay(2000)
sleep2.then((x) => console.log(x || 'wakeup 2'))
wake2('Custom Wakeup') // sleep2 cancelled will wake from wake2 call
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [`AbortSignal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal):

```
function delay(ms, signal) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    function done() {
      resolve();
      signal?.removeEventListener("abort", stop);
    }
    function stop() {
      reject(this.reason);
      clearTimeout(handle);
    }
    signal?.throwIfAborted();
    const handle = setTimeout(done, ms);
    signal?.addEventListener("abort", stop);
  });
}
```

Example:

```
const controller = new AbortController()
delay(9000, controller.signal).then(() => {
  console.log('Finished sleeping');
}, err => {
  if (!controller.signal.aborted) throw err;
  // alternatively:
  if (err.name != "AbortError") throw err;

  console.log('Cancelled sleep before it went over 9000')
});
button.onclick => () => {
  controller.abort();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, is this some new JS feature ?

Comment: @TSR It's not part of ECMAScript but of the Web APIs, however also supported by nodejs. It's been around for a while (2017 IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

You can return a function which cancels the timer (`cancelTimer`) along with the `Promise` object as an array from the `delay` function call.

Then use the `cancelTimer` to clear it if required and which would also reject the `Promise`:

```js
function delay(millis) {
  let cancelTimer;
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("done");
    }, millis);
    cancelTimer = () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutID);
      reject("Promise cancelled");
    };
  });
  return [promise, cancelTimer];
}

//DEMO
let [promiseCancelled, cancelTimer] = delay(20000);
(async() => {
  try {
    console.log("Promise result never printed", await promiseCancelled);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Promise is rejected", error);
  }
})();
cancelTimer();

const [promise, _] = delay(2000);
(async() => {
  console.log("Promise result printed", await promise);
})();
```

Comment: If you only clear the timeout like that, all the code that would have hooked to the Promise will stay pending forever.

Comment: @Kaiido yes you are right, I have fixed that problem otherwise it would have caused a memory leak. In the updated code I would reject the `Promise` when the timeout is cancelled through a function `cancelTimer`.

Comment: And your solution now becomes *very* similar to the accepted one ;)

Comment: @Kaiido yes almost :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you do not modify the promise by attaching an `.abort` method to it. Instead return *two* values from your delay function

1. the delayed value
2. a function that can be called to cancel the timeout

Critically, we do not see `"x"` logged to the console because it was canceled -

```js
function useDelay (x = null, ms = 1000)
{ let t
  return [
    new Promise(r => t = setTimeout(r, ms, x)), // 1
    _ => clearTimeout(t)                        // 2
  ]
}

const [x, abortX] =
  useDelay("x", 5000)
  
const [y, abortY] =
  useDelay("y canceled x", 2000)
  
x.then(console.log, console.error)

y.then(console.log, console.error).finally(_ => abortX())

console.log("loading...")

// loading...
// y canceled x
```

---

**interactive demo**

Here's an interactive example that allows you to wait for a delayed value or abort it -

```js
function useDelay (x = null, ms = 1000)
{ let t
  return [
    new Promise(r => t = setTimeout(r, ms, x)), // 1
    _ => clearTimeout(t)                        // 2
  ]
}

const [ input, output ] =
  document.querySelectorAll("input")
  
const [go, abort] =
  document.querySelectorAll("button")
  
let loading = false

function reset ()
{ loading = false
  input.value = ""
  go.disabled = false
  abort.disabled = true
}

function load ()
{ loading = true
  go.disabled = true
  abort.disabled = false
}

go.onclick = e => {
  if (loading) return
  load()
    
  const [delayedValue, abortValue] =
    useDelay(input.value, 3000)
    
  abort.onclick = _ => {
    abortValue()
    reset()
  }
  
  delayedValue
    .then(v => output.value = v)
    .catch(e => output.value = e.message)
    .finally(_ => reset())
}
```

```css
code { color: dodgerblue; }
```

```html
<input placeholder="enter a value..." />
<button>GO</button>
<button disabled>ABORT</button>
<input disabled placeholder="waiting for output..." />

<p>Click <code>GO</code> and the value will be transferred to the output in 5 seconds.</p>
<p>If you click <code>ABORT</code> the transfer will be canceled.</p>
```

Comment: Any reasoning against modifying the Promise returned? Note that it's not the Promise's proto that's being modified, but only a new method attached to the one instance. Also, your code is creating for ever pending Promises, and any hooks on that Promise will also be forever pending.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `AbortSignal`:

```js
/**
 * Sleep for the specified number of milliseconds, or until the abort
 * signal gets triggered.
 * 
 * @param ms {number}
 * @param signal {AbortSignal|undefined}
 */
const sleep = (ms, signal) =>
  new Promise<void>((ok, ng) => {
    /** @type {number} */
    let timeout

    const abortHandler = () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout)

      const aborted = new Error(`sleep aborted`)
      aborted.name = 'AbortError'

      ng(aborted)
    }
    signal?.addEventListener('abort', abortHandler)

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      signal?.removeEventListener('abort', abortHandler)
      ok()
    }, ms)
  })
```

```
> const a = new AbortController()
undefined
> const s = sleep(900000, a.signal)
undefined
> a.abort()
undefined
> await s
Uncaught AbortError: sleep aborted
    at AbortSignal.abortHandler
    at innerInvokeEventListeners
    at invokeEventListeners
    at dispatch
    at AbortSignal.dispatchEvent
    at AbortSignal.[[[signalAbort]]]
    at AbortController.abort
    at <anonymous>:2:3
>
```

If you prefer not to fail the promise, i.e. treat the abort signal as "skip sleep", simply replace the call to `ng(aborted)` with a call to `ok()`.

Comment: Don't forget to immediately reject/resolve the promise if the signal is already `.aborted`, like in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74671353/1048572)