# How to cancel `setTimeout` after Promisification

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, es6-promise, cancellation

I'm using setTimeout as a Promise. But then I cannot cancel it using `clearTimeout`. THis is my code:

```js
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));
delay(1000).then(() => console.log("Done"));
```

But using this approach I cannot cancel timeout using clearTimeout.
I tried `promisify` nestjs function but still cannot do this

Comment: How does your `clearTimeout` part look like?

Comment: You can't, as written, you need to return something like a deferred object or a then-able with other methods for cancellation etc.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot cancel a promise from outside. You need to decide when and how the promise should be resolved when you create the promise. To cancel the task (in this case, the timer), pass a [cancellation signal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal) as an argument.

You don't have to use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`, and you don't have to promisify them. Instead, just use the builtin [`setTimeout` from `node:timers/promises`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timerspromisessettimeoutdelay-value-options) that already provides this functionality:

> ```
> const { setTimeout } = require('node:timers/promises');
>
> const ac = new AbortController();
> const signal = ac.signal;
>
> setTimeout(1000, 'foobar', { signal })
>   .then(console.log)
>   .catch((err) => {
>     if (err.name === 'AbortError')
>       console.error('The timeout was aborted');
>   });
>
> ac.abort();
> ```

If you want to implement this yourself, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74671353/1048572) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

To create a cancelable delay using Promises, you can wrap setTimeout in a way that allows you to keep track of the timeout ID and then use that ID to cancel the timeout if needed. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
class CancelablePromiseDelay {
constructor(ms) {
this.ms = ms;
this.timeoutId = null;
this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.resolve = resolve;
  this.reject = reject;
  this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    resolve();
    this.timeoutId = null;
  }, ms);
  });
 }

  cancel() {
   if (this.timeoutId !== null) {
  clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
  this.timeoutId = null;
  this.reject(new Error('Delay canceled'));
   }
  }
   }

     const delay = (ms) => new CancelablePromiseDelay(ms);

   const delayPromise = delay(1000);

     delayPromise
  .then(() => console.log('Done'))
     .catch((error) => console.error(error));

 // To cancel the delay
  // delayPromise.cancel();
```

Comment: It worth mention that if you forgot to reject the promise, once you cancelled the setTimeout task, you're going to wait forever. Another point is the mandatory of using catch, or a `try {} catch() {}` to avoid error when cancel a setTimeout.