# How to cancel an async operation properly in React / TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, cancellation, abort

I have this to check if my server is alive, polling every 10 seconds for a max of 10 times to see if it's alive.

```
const wait = (ms: number) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

export async function checkRemote(
  { maxAttempts = 10 }: { maxAttempts: number } = { maxAttempts: 10 }
) {
  let i = 1;
  while (true) {
    const res = await fetch(`/check`);
    if (res.status >= 400) {
      if (i === maxAttempts) {
        throw new Error("Check failed");
      } else {
        i++;
        await wait(10000);
        continue;
      }
    } else {
      const json = await res.json();
      return json;
    }
  }
}
```

How can I properly "cancel" this polling in the context of React.js?

The problem is, my `checkRemote` function is going to continue to execute after my React component unmounts... If it unmounts while the calls are still ongoing.

First of all, the call to `checkRemote` *must* be made in a `useEffect` hook, *not* as the result of a button click? Or can we make it occur on button click (that would be ideal IMO), but still make it cancelable if they unmount the current component?

```
useEffect(() => {
  const promise = checkRemote({ maxAttempts: 10 })
    .then(res => {
      setStatus('ready')
    }).catch(e => {
      setStatus('unvailable')
    })

  return () => {
    // on unmount, do something like this?
    promise.abort()
  }
})
```

Or perhaps for button click:

```
const [checkPromise, setCheckPromise] = useState<Promise>()

const handleClick = () => {
  const promise = checkRemote({ maxAttempts: 10 })
    .then((res) => {
      setStatus("ready");
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      setStatus("unvailable");
    });
  
  setCheckPromise(promise)
}

useEffect(() => {
  return () => checkPromise.abort()
}, [checkPromise])

return <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
```

How could I architect this to pass in the "promise abort handler" into my nested functions? Something like `AbortController`....

```
const wait = (ms: number, { controller }) => {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    let timer = setTimeout(res, ms)

    controller.on('abort', () => {
      clearTimeout(timer)
      // to respond or not respond then?
      res()
    })
  })
}

export async function checkRemote(
  { maxAttempts = 10, controller }: { maxAttempts: number } = {
    maxAttempts: 10,
  }
) {
  let i = 1;
  while (!controller.aborted) {
    const res = await fetch(`/check`, { signal: controller });
    if (res.status >= 400) {
      if (i === maxAttempts) {
        throw new Error("Check failed");
      } else {
        i++;
        // somehow stop the timer early if we abort
        await wait(10000, { controller });
        continue;
      }
    } else {
      const json = await res.json();
      return json;
    }
  }
}
```

If I go down this rabbit hole, what are your recommendations? How do I architect the system to abort every function "properly"? I would probably use a custom event emitter to do this I'm guessing, so I can have `controller.on('abort')` easily throughout.

What I don't want to happen is my 10 second * 10 attempt = ~2 minute checker continues to check when the component is unmounted, that would be painful and confusing. I would like for it to cancel everything on unmount basically.

Note: the general problem is how to setup async aborting, not to `useContext` or something *for this specific use case*.

Comment: You should only pass the `AbortSignal`, not the `AbortController` (and name your parameters accordingly), but otherwise yes that's the way to go

Comment: As for how to cancel the `setTimeout` in `wait`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74671353/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

Besides using a simple AbortController and using the `throwIfAborted`method and/or `abort` event, you can use any library that provides its own cancelable/abortable Promise.

The following is not a recommended way, as I created this library myself and it is in beta, so this is just a suggestion:
([Live playground](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/promise1-gsh7cd?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.mjs%3A24%2C8))

```js
import { AxiosPromise } from 'axios-promise';

const wait = AxiosPromise.delay;

const cancelableFetch = (url, opt) =>
  new AxiosPromise((resolve, _, { signal }) => {
    resolve(fetch(url, {...opt, signal}));
  });

const checkRemote = AxiosPromise.promisify(function* (url, { maxAttempts = 10 } = {}) {
  let i = 1;
  for (;;) {
    try {
      console.log(`request [${i}]`);

      const res = yield cancelableFetch(url);

      const simulateFailure = i < 3;

      if (res.status < 400 && !simulateFailure) {
        return yield res.json();
      }
    } finally {
      if (i++ === maxAttempts) {
        throw new Error('Check failed');
      }
    }
    yield wait(5000);
  }
});

// ------------ test env ----------------
const runButton = document.querySelector('#run');
const cancelButton = document.querySelector('#cancel');
let promise;

cancelButton.onclick = () => {
  promise?.cancel();
};

runButton.onclick = () => {
  promise?.cancel(new Error('restart'));

  promise = checkRemote(`https://dummyjson.com/products/1?delay=1000`).then(
    (json) => console.log(`Done:`, json),
    (err) => console.log(`Fail: ${err}`)
  );
};
```